# TypeScript import {Foo}　と　import Fooの違い

Tags: typescript

タイトルのとおり、波括弧をつけた場合との違い及び
`defalt export`と　`export` オンリーとの違いがわかりません。教えてください。

Comment: 参考: 英語版での関連質問(とその回答) - [difference between import … and import {…} (with curly braces)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38729486)